# run code in pycharm at office then fail to run the same code in pycharm at home?

Tags: python, ide, pycharm

**Symptom:**

I ran some code in pycharm at office, which I sync in google driver so that I can access them at home. But when I run the same code in pycharm at home, it keeps throwing me an error that it can't find the file specified, which is the path to the python interpreter in my office computer.

**Tried:**

I tried to locate the project interpreter setting and make sure the path to the interpreter is to the python at my home computer. But it still won't work. I tried to google it, nothing comes up. Anyone has the same issue before?

**Error running scraper:**

> Cannot run program
>   "C:\Users\Administrator.SUNDAN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\python.exe"
>   (in directory
>   "D:\baiduyundownload\Tempo\Office\1107\Projects\Code\scraper"):
>   CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

**Notice that the path:**

```
"C:\Users\Administrator.SUNDAN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\python.exe"
```

leads to the python interpreter at office.

**Related info:**

OS: WINDOWS 10

Python Version: 3.5

Comment: Are you sure that the file is in your home computer at the specified path too?

Comment: No, let's be clear, the file that pycharm complains about is the python interpreter, and I check the project interpreter setting to make sure it's corrrectly configured. What's odd is that it throws the error that it can't find the python whose path is to my python at office.

Comment: @陈嘉奇, you're probably copying _the whole project_ to your home computer, with all settings that apply only to Pycharm at work. If you try to compose a new project with only the `.py` files (no configs), it may work.

Comment: @ForceBru Yes, I am copying the whole project, since I synced them in google drive. And I am able to run .py files in a new project in pycharm. But my project has no configs files either, it's just .py files with a folder structure to group them into modules and packages. Also worth mentioning is that it worked yesterday when I tried to run code at home.

Comment: There are project settings in the `.idea` folder. I have a similar problem with Android Studio and the Java class path. You will need to browse the Preferences to set them for each computer. Ideally you should push the main files to git (github) and allow each computer to set up the appropriate project files to run it on that computer.